# Capture session closes the camera

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession

I have an issue which I don't know what might cause it. So I want to be able to scan the QR code using the camera but immediately I set data to the capture session app closes and even the phone is locked. Nothing has been reported in the `Output` which is weird except `XPC connection interrupted`. Didn't find a correlation between the issue I have and this output.

Worth mentioning is that the same code basically copy-paste worked in the brand-new project I created for testing purposes. So the camera and QR code scanning worked.

My assumption is that something went wrong in the project configuration and I don't know what.

The code is the following:

```
 guard let videoCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back) else {
        print("Camera access failed")
        return
        
    }
            
    do {
        let videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice)
        captureSession.addInput(videoInput)
    } catch {
        failed()
        return
    }
    
    let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
    
    captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)
    metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
    
    guard metadataOutput.availableMetadataObjectTypes.contains(.qr) else {return}
    metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr]
    
    
    let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    previewLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds
    previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
    view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer) 
    startScanner() 
    }
  // View Did Load ends here

   func startScanner() {
    
    // Check camera usage permission
    switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video) {
    case .authorized:
        print("Scan View Controller || Permission to use camera granted")
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            self.captureSession.startRunning()
        }
    case .notDetermined:
        print("Scan View Controller || Permission to use camera not determined")
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { granted in
            if granted {
                DispatchQueue.global().async {
                    self.captureSession.startRunning()
                }
            }
        }
    case .denied:
        print("Scan View Controller || Permission to use camera denied")
        return
    case .restricted:
        return
    @unknown default:
        return
    }
}
```

But immediately the screen is started the result is the following image:

[image]

Or check the video in Reddit question:
https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/11l6tht/xpc_connection_interrupted_capture_session/

Logs:

```
[Camera] Attempted to change to mode Portrait with an unsupported device (BackWideDual). Auto device for both positions unsupported, returning Auto device for same position anyway (BackAuto).
2023-03-15 11:37:02.712147+0100 Cykelrum.se[32955:2282104] XPC connection interrupted
2023-03-15 11:37:02.718057+0100 Cykelrum.se[32955:2281900] [Common] [FBSOrientationObserverClient:0x281638240] Service suspended: the connection with the service host has been interrupted.
2023-03-15 11:37:02.718447+0100 Cykelrum.se[32955:2282104] [Common] [SBSSystemServiceClient:0x28162d260] Service suspended: the connection with the service host has been interrupted.
2023-03-15 11:37:03.194068+0100 Cykelrum.se[32955:2282102] [Common] [FBSOrientationObserverClient:0x281638240] Service suspended: the connection with the service host has been interrupted.
2023-03-15 11:37:03.205360+0100 Cykelrum.se[32955:2282104] [Common] [SBSSystemServiceClient:0x28162d260] Service suspended: the connection with the service host has been interrupted.
```

Comment: Did you setup entitlements properly? Do you ask the user for permissions elsewhere in your code? Is all the code related to `previewLayer` guaranteed to be running on main thread?

Comment: @rapiddevice thanks for the comment. So I think yes to all. The app does have camera permission and there is just 1 place I ask for it. `previewLayer` is only used in that part I shared. Basically, if I comment out the code starting from this part `guard metadataOutput...` to the end, of course, camera will not work but this bug will stop happening. Can't figure out what might be the cause in that few lines.

Comment: Comment out metadata, and enable preview - does it happen then? And vice versa: disable preview, but leave metadata active. See which of them is a problem

Comment: @rapiddevice so definitely commenting out just this part `captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)` will stop this bug but again only blank screen without camera running.

Comment: @rapiddevice one more thing I noticed, for instance, changing the param here `AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video)` to anything else besides `.video` will also stop that bug. I also tried with one library for QR code scanning and the same thing is happening even when I use that library.

Comment: @rapiddevice is also worth mentioning in the brand-new project the same code works (copy-paste), the camera is started and QR code scanning works. So seems that something in the project configuration went wrong.

Comment: And where/how do you start capture session?

Comment: The way I'd identify what is missing is by running your copy-pasted project, and save the console output.  Then repeat with your original project, recording the console output.  You will then be able to see what is present in the working one over the broken one.  They'll be logs against the critical items, e.g. entitlements, but note they originate from other services (so don't filter down your logs).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately without the full stack trace it's hard to tell what the problem is.

> In general it is not to safe to mutate an AVCaptureSession or any of
> its inputs, outputs, or connections from multiple threads at the same
> time.

I recommend creating your own queue, and use that instead of getting a global queue for all the operations with **AVFoundation**:

```
let sessionQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.name.AVFoundation", attributes: [], autoreleaseFrequency: .workItem)


sessionQueue.async {

}
```

I also noticed that your session configuration not completely correct:

> You should call beginConfiguration method before changing a session’s
> inputs or outputs, and call commitConfiguration method after making
> changes.